# Aphrodite Server Side render under npm link

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I currently have a simple React component in one npm module (we'll call it `simple-react`) and a simple express app in another one (we'll call it `express-app`), with the following properties:

1. `express-app` depends on `simple-react`.
2. `simple-react` uses Aphrodite for style encapsulation.
3. `express-app` uses Aphrodite's `StyleSheetServer.renderStatic` to render the encapsulated styles server side.
4. `simple-react` is built with Webpack with Aphrodite declared as an external.

Now this whole setup is working great for both server side and client side rendering, I love it. The only hangup I have is when I try to perform server side rendering under while `simple-react` is npm linked. Since  `StyleSheetServer.renderStatic` sets internal state to buffer to a string instead of a DOM Node, finding the correct version of Aphrodite in `simple-react` is very important. While linked, `simple-react` requires in Aphrodite from its own `node_modules` directory as its a devDependency. Even if it wasn't there though, `simple-react` cannot find the same Aphrodite library as `express-app` is using. This causes a render error on the server side as `simple-react`'s Aphrodite tries to buffer to a DOM Node, even though its running inside a `StyleSheetServer.renderStatic` call stack.

The error is `Error: Cannot automatically buffer without a document`. If I manually remove Aphrodite from `simple-react`'s `node_modules` directory the error becomes: `Cannot find module 'aphrodite'`.

I do a have hacky solution, outlined below, but I'm thinking there has to be a better solution out there.

Inside `express-app`:

```
const aphrodite = require('aphrodite');
global.aphrodite = aphrodite;
const simple = require('simple-react');
```

Inside `simple-react`:

```
if(typeof global !== 'undefined' && global.aphrodite){
    var { StyleSheet, css } = global.aphrodite;
}
else{
    var { StyleSheet, css } = require('aphrodite');
}
```

Like I said, hacky. Any ideas?

(I'd tag `aphrodite` if there was a tag for it)